eCPPTv2 Buffer overflow exploit development
I'm having ecPPTv2 exam, and I successfully developed the exploit for the buffer overflow section, so I found offset, bad chars and the return address, i debugged with Immunity Debugger and It's all good, the rutn pointer is ok and no ASLR is active in that address BUT when I debug it as soon as i hit the start of my payload I get
Access violation when executing [ESP Address]
Initially I thought it was normal, 'cause I am running Immunity on a windows 11 machine but when I try to execute the program into the kali machine to attack the target I don't receive the connection back to my handler
I tried to change NOP, changereturn address but nothing worked
Can you help me?

Try temporarily turning off Data Execution Prevention in Windows:

"Tap the Windows key or Start button".

"Type Windows Security and select the Windows Security app that appears at the top of the search results."

"Select App & browser control and then Exploit protection."


"You'll find Data Execution Prevention on the System settings tab."

Thank you! I did it and the debugger worked fine, the exploit completed!
Now the question is, why it's not working on the target machine?
I am attacking using proxychains, maybe there is something that i did not do after autorouting?

@niccolòorlandi Sorry, I'm not familiar with these tools (proxychains, kali, Immunity).  Please ask a followup question or update this question (noting that it now works on Windows).  Please add more details about how you're connecting to the target machine.
